# Python Plotly: Not maintaining axes when using String formatted dates instead of Numeric

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bar-chart, axes

I'm encountering a strange problem with plotly and pandas where the axes are flipping when I use a formatted date string instead of an int for the month.

I created this group from my dataset:

```
dfg = dfq.groupby(['Target', 'Mon','Month_fr','Year'])['Value'].mean().reset_index()

Target    Mon Mon_fr Yr     Value
Aggression  1   Jan 2020    0.393939
Aggression  2   Feb 2020    0.181818
Aggression  3   Mar 2020    0.430556
Aggression  4   Apr 2020    0.159420
Aggression  5   May 2020    0.445783
Aggression  6   Jun 2020    0.446154
Aggression  7   Jul 2019    0.620690
Aggression  8   Aug 2019    0.692308
Aggression  9   Sep 2019    0.207792
Aggression  10  Oct 2019    0.287671
Aggression  11  Nov 2019    0.253968
Aggression  12  Dec 2019    0.461538
Off-Task    1   Jan 2020    0.818182
Off-Task    2   Feb 2020    0.606061
Off-Task    3   Mar 2020    0.643836
Off-Task    4   Apr 2020    0.710145
Off-Task    5   May 2020    1.084337
Off-Task    6   Jun 2020    1.014925
Off-Task    7   Jul 2019    1.137931
Off-Task    8   Aug 2019    0.846154
Off-Task    9   Sep 2019    0.701299
Off-Task    10  Oct 2019    0.794521
Off-Task    11  Nov 2019    0.730159
Off-Task    12  Dec 2019    0.984615
SIB         1   Jan 2020    0.492308
SIB         2   Feb 2020    0.045455
SIB         3   Mar 2020    0.154930
SIB         4   Apr 2020    0.289855
SIB         5   May 2020    0.192771
SIB         6   Jun 2020    0.164179
SIB         7   Jul 2019    0.086207
SIB         8   Aug 2019    0.415385
SIB         9   Sep 2019    0.434211
SIB         10  Oct 2019    0.301370
SIB         11  Nov 2019    0.245902
SIB         12  Dec 2019    0.507692
```

and wish to plot side by side bar charts with "Value" on the y-axis

This works fine when I use the numeric month value:

```
fig = px.bar(dfg, x=["Target", "Mon"], y="Value", color = "Target",title="Behavior Data",barmode="group")
fig.show()
```

[image]

But when I try to do the same using formatted month variable:

```
fig = px.bar(dfg, x=["Target", "Month_fr"], y="Value", color = "Target",title="Behavior Data",barmode="group")
fig.show()
```

It flips the  axes and  no  longer  uses "Values" as the data being represented:

[image]

Have any of you good people came across this bizarre problem before?! HELP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! The issue was that I had the values for x entered as a list:

```
x=["Target", "Month_fr"],
```

Unbeknownst to me I didn't need to include "Target" in my x variable as that grouping is handled by "color = 'Target'"... quite why this wan't a problem when using an integer for the months I don't know. There may be some issue with using 2 string values as the x value.

Thanks for anyone who considered! Here is the working code if you happen to be interested:

```
import plotly.express as px  # (version 4.7.0)

fig = px.bar(dfg, x="Month_fr", y="Value", color = "Target",title="Behavior Data",barmode="group")
fig.show()
```